# How to serve images on Spring based web services

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a java web service for the first time. I am using Spring Framework to do it. I need to serve user images. I will get Base64 String from the client and write it as an image and add its reachable url to database than whenever a client wants to see this image I will just send the image url and by this way a client will be able to use the image with less effort.
But to do this I need to reach these images in their folder via browser.
I don't know how to reach a folder and its files on java based web services.I hope someone helps.

If there is a way you think better to do. Please feel free to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Framework 4.1 has improved support for resource handling. It allows you to declaratively configure from where to serve resources for a certain request path, and that's what you're probably interested in.

In your code, making file system resources accessible from the web mostly boils down to overriding the `addResourceHandlers()` method of your `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` based configuration class. The [Spring Framework documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources) shows the following example:

> For example, to serve resource requests with a URL pattern of /resources/** from a public-resources directory within the web application root you would use:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/public-resources/");
    }

}
```

Substitute `/public-resources/` with your filesystem path prefixed with `file://`, e.g. `file://user-uploads/`.

I suggest taking a look at the [relevant blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources) and the accompanying [example project](https://github.com/bclozel/spring-resource-handling). The demo project sports [a good example](https://github.com/bclozel/spring-resource-handling/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/resources/WebConfig.java#L87-L108) of how to configure resource handling for a complex scenario.